# Does TCP ensure packet is received by sequence that server send it

Tags: sockets, tcp

I'm working on an gameServer that communicate with game client, but wonder whether the packet server send to client remain sequence when client received it ?

like server sends packets A,B,C
but the client received B,A,C ?

I have read the great blog http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/
It seems that every packet send by the server has an ack corresponding by client, but it does not say why the packet received by client has the same sequence with server

Comment: @PSkocik you mean a single TCP packet may be splite to several IP datagram which has no order guarantee,  and It will get reassembled  correctly to origin TCP packet ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It applies just as well to entire segments.

Comment: NB Poor quality citation. The three-way handshake is not 'infamous', at least not for any cogent reason advanced in the citation. 'Client on either side of a TCP session' is a contradiction in terms. There isn't anything there that actually answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth reading [TCP's RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), particularly section 1.5 (Operation), which explains the process. In part, it says:

> The TCP must recover from data that is damaged, lost, duplicated, or delivered out of order by the internet communication system.  This is achieved by assigning a sequence number to each octet transmitted, and requiring a positive acknowledgment (ACK) from the receiving TCP.  If the ACK is not received within a timeout interval, the data is retransmitted.  At the receiver, the sequence numbers are used to correctly order segments that may be received out of order and to eliminate duplicates.  Damage is handled by adding a checksum to each segment transmitted, checking it at the receiver, and discarding damaged segments.

I don't see where it's ever made explicit, but since the acknowledgement (as described in section 2.6) describes the *next expected packet*, the receiving TCP implementation is only ever acknowledging consecutive sequences of packets from the beginning. That is, if you never receive the first packet, you never send an acknowledgement, even if you've received all other packets in the message; if you've received 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6, you only acknowledge 1-3.

For completeness, I'd also direct your attention to section 2.6, again, after it describes the above-quoted section in more detail:

> An acknowledgment by TCP does not guarantee that the data has been delivered to the end user, but only that the receiving TCP has taken the responsibility to do so.

So, TCP ensures the order of packets, *unless* the application doesn't receive them. That exception probably wouldn't be common, except for cases where the application is unavailable, but it does mean that an application shouldn't assume that a successful send is equivalent to a successful reception. It *probably* is, for a variety of reasons, but it's explicitly outside of the protocol's scope.

Answer (score 1):

TCP guarantees sequence and integrity of the byte stream. You will not receive data out of sequence. From [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> Reliable Communication: A stream of data sent on a TCP connection is delivered reliably and in
> order at the destination.